# Mapping array to components fails in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a MealList component which lists an array of Meal components.

```
const MealList = (props) => {
    console.log(props.meals);// [Array(3)]

    return (
        <div style={{width: '70%'}}>
            <h3 style={{color: 'grey', fontSize: '1.4em', fontWeight: '700', marginBottom: '1em'}}><FontAwesomeIcon
                icon={faPlusCircle} style={{color: '#007bff', marginRight: '0.5em'}}/> ADD MEAL</h3>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Meal</th>
                    <th>Calories</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Update</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.meals.map(meal => <Meal label={meal.label} calories={meal.calories} time={meal.time}
                                               date={meal.date}/>)}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>

    )
};
export default MealList;
```

This is the structure of the array on the console.

```
[Array(3)]
0: Array(3)
0: {id: 8, label: "Breakfast", calories: 311, time: "20:10:00", date: "2019-12-29", …}
1: {id: 9, label: "Lunch", calories: 721, time: "20:10:00", date: "2019-12-29", …}
2: {id: 10, label: "Dinner", calories: 663, time: "20:10:00", date: "2019-12-29", …}
length: 3
```

Inside the Meal component though the props value render undefined.

```
const Meal = (props) => {
    console.log(props.label, props.calories, props.time, props.data);//undefined ....

    return (<tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>{props.label}</td>
        <td>{props.calories}</td>
        <td>{props.time}</td>
        <td>{props.date}</td>
        <td><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUserEdit}/></td>
        <td><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinusCircle}/></td>
    </tr>);
};
export default Meal;
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code works fine, https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-bhaskara-30nf5, next time try add a producible example beforehand, it takes 1 min and 30 sec

Comment: What do your meal objects look like? Can you console log `props.meals` in your `MealList` component and paste the output here?

Comment: My guess is that the data is fetched asynchronously somewhere else and this is why this is failing. It didn't crashed because of what [skyboyer said (array of array)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59523445/1218980), but you need to handle the initial state where the array is either empty or unavailable, like `null` or `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

According to

```
[Array(3)]
```

your `props.meals` is not array of objects but array(with single element) of array of objects.

So while quickfix would be

```
{props.meals[0].map(meal =>
```

better to check why it's coming in different structure rather you expect

Comment: `console.log(props.meals[0]);` gives `(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]` however when I try to map meals[0] I get the following error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

- In the meal list component, before mapping on the props.meal check first if props.meal is not null otherwise show a message or something
- [array[3]] means that the meal has one element which is an array of 3 elements, so try to adjust the structure of the data you are sending to the meals list
- try to send to the meal component a meal object rather then meal.label , meal.date and so on, this way you have completely isolated reusable components

Comment: Your last point is rather opinionated, where both ways are equally valid depending on the use-case. In OP's code, the `Meal` component renders data regardless of the structure of the `meal` object.

Comment: yeah that's absolutely correct, I mentioned that it is only suggestion to make the meal component isolated and to make every component responsible for only one thing